# Select all the clients that are in the hotel between two dates knowing tha date of arrival and departue

Tags: sql, date, select

I have a table clients with the date the client arrive and the date the client depart.

I want to select which clients stays in the hotel at least one day between 18-10-2019 and 22-10-2019.
For example: 
I have:

```
Client Arrive      Depart
1      16-10-2019  18-10-2019
2      16-10-2019  17-10-2019
3      21-10-2019  30-10-2019
```

I want:

```
Client Arrive      Depart
1      16-10-2019  18-10-2019
3      21-10-2019  30-10-2019
```

I've tried this: 
Select * from clients where cl_Arrive between "18/10/2019" and "22/10/2019"

But like this i don't take into account the depart date.

Comment: Make it possible to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: With Postgres this is as easy as `where daterange(arrive, depart, '[]') && daterange(date '2019-10-2019', date '2019-10-22', '[]')` - which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for hotel stays whose dates *overlap* the target range. For this, you can use the following conditions:

```
arrive <= :EndDate and depart >= :StartDate
```

In your example, `:StartDate` is 18-10-2019 and `:EndDate` is 22-10-2019.

These conditions would typically go in the `where` clause of your query:

```
select *
from mytable
where arrive <= @EndDate and depart >= @StartDate
```